# MySQL SELECT query not returning all results

Tags: mysql

Query is below:

```
SELECT employeeid
     , firstname
     , lastname
     , title
     , supervisor
     , location
     , room
     , extension
     , email
     , positiontype
     , active
     , photo
  FROM employees 
 WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(employeeid, firstname, lastname, title, supervisor, location, room, extension, email, positiontype, active, photo)) LIKE LOWER("%' . $searchcriteria . '%")
```

This is a search function, so essentially someone would search for 'Smith' and this is supposed to return a list of anyone that has a matching name, position, anything. The issue is, if a person has a NULL field in the database, such as a NULL extension for people who do not have phone extensions, it excludes them entirely from the search. I am not smart enough with mySQL to know how to fix this, even though I am sure it is something very easy.

Thank you for looking

Comment: Use `CONCAT_WS('', {columns list})` - it skips NULLs instead of return NULL.

Comment: You're amazing, thank you!

Comment: Let's hope that the data set never grows above, say, 100 rows

Comment: Depending on your collations, and column types,  you don't need lower as with default collations the VARCHAR column is case insensitive.